# When making an ajax call I receive "TypeError: e is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-get-contents

I am trying to display the contents of a website by using file_get_contents in a PHP script and ajax on the front-end. I can display the whole page just fine but if I try to only display a certain amount of images on the page, than I receive the "TypeError: e is undefined" error. Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
    $url= 'https://twitter.com/twitter';
    if($url!="")
        echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
    url : "twitter.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success : function (data) {
        console.log("loaded");
        //$(data).appendTo('#images');
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
            $("<img />").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
            if (i == 5) return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an HTML string, to iterate over it (like a DOM tree) using jQ, you'll have to call the jQ constructor (or `init` method). Which you actually did when you tried to append it to the current dom:

```
  $(data).appendTo('#images');
// \==>$() is a function call, returns a jQ instance
//         When passing a markup string, jQ will parse it for you
```

The loop, therefore, should look like:

```
$.each($(data), function(){});
```

And please, do try adding in a couple of `console.log` statements, that will help you a lot when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that `data.items` will be undefined. I'm guessing that `data` is of type string, as you're expecting HTML back. So you're going to be receiving the HTML for the webpage, which you'd have to parse yourself.